# Custom action bar stops my app

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, ide

I want use custom action bar so I set custom action bar in my app but when I cant run app.app force stopping.
I make a a toolbar lay out in res/layout and disable default actionbar and then set custom action bar in MainActivity.
this is my toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- This is a centered logo -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
    <!-- This is a centered title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

this is my MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);

    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu); 
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); 
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); 
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In the future, when your app crashes post the stacktrace of your error so that we can have more info and we can help you better solve your error. This issue i'm seeing here is that your Toolbar element in the xml is outside the FrameLayout, remember that each xml file can have at most one root element.

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <!-- This is a centered logo -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
    <!-- This is a centered title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

You might also want to look at other ViewGroups to arrange the elements in your xml, such as CoordinatorLayout and LinearLayout.

Comment: @Mr.Mr i've updated my answer to be more explicit. If this doesn't work make sure to edit your answer with the error stack trace so that myself and other people in the community can help.

Comment: I found the problem.When I remove "setSupportActionBar(tb);" app is working.But actionbar not change.